# Fork call and recursion

Tags: fork

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    fork();
    fork();
    fork();

    puts("hi");

    return 0;
}
```

This program prints 8 times "hi" and exits.
Why? Is not each `fork` calling `main` recursively
as in: `f(): "hi"; f()`?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is purely a C issue and has nothing to do with *nix.

Comment: @terdon You could argue programming questions are off-topic, but you can't really say fork is "purely C" since it is a system call primarily associated with \*nix and POSIX operating systems, with behavior that happens to "break" the normal rules of "pure" C. You won't find any mention of "fork" in the C standard.

Comment: @jw013 I am about as far from a C expert as it is possible to be so I may very well be wrong. Are you saying that any code that contains `fork` is by definition one that will only run on *nix? So questions about `fork` specifically should be on topic?

Comment: @terdon *"any code that contains `fork` is by definition one that will only run on \*nix"* - There may be rare exceptions or corner cases I am unaware of, but this is the general rule.

Comment: @jw013 fair enough, question reopened. Thanks for the pointer (no pun intended).

Answer (score 11):

No, `fork` is not "recursive" in the traditional meaning of recursion.  A call to `fork()` duplicates the current process so it "returns twice".  For the child process, the return value is 0, and for the parent the return value is the child PID.  `fork()` does *not* restart `main` - that would be more like `fork` followed by `exec`.

Your program works like this.  First let's insert some line numbers:

```
 1: #include <stdio.h>
 2: #include <stdlib.h>
 3: #include <string.h>
 4:
 5: int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 6: {
 7:    fork();
 8:    fork();
 9:    fork();
10:
11:    puts("hi");
12:
13:    return 0;
14: }
```

Let's say you start your program and it gets a PID of *P*.

- After line 7, the call to `fork` results in two separate processes, *both at line 8*, one with PID *P* (the original) and one with a pid of *C1* (the new child).
- *P* runs line 8 and spawns a new child, with PID *C2*.  Both *P* and *C2* are at line 9 now.  Meanwhile, *C1* runs line 8 and spawns a new child, *CC1*.  Both *CC1* and *C1* are at line 9 as well.  (Not entirely relevant, but the order in which the above two sentences occur is indeterminate.  They could happen simultaneously on multi-processor systems.)

There are now a total of 4 processes: *P*, *C1*, *C2*, and *CC1*.  As you can see, each successive `fork` doubles the amount of processes.  Since there are 3 `fork` calls, you end up with 2<sup>3</sup> or 8 processes.  The genealogy looks something like:

```
P (initial process, started by you)
+-- C1 (created on line 7)
|   +-- CC1 (created on line 8)
|   |   +-- CCC1 (created on line 9)
|   +-- CC2 (created on line 9)
+-- C2 (created on line 8)
|   +-- CC3 (created on line 9)
+-- C3 (created on line 9)
```

Each process is created by its parent in the tree.

Comment: I think the misconception that the OP had was the fork started at the beginning of main again.  This answer clearly illustrates that fork creates two processes at the same location.  (If you were trying to create a [fork bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb) you need something like this `while (1) fork();`).

Answer (score 3):

```
                           main()
                             |
                             |
                      fork()  ------------------
                              |                 |
                     fork()   -------        -------
                              |     |        |      |
                   fork()   ----   ----     ---    ---
                            |  |   |   |    |  |   |  |
```

This is the process tree of above code that's how the fork() works.and why its printing 8 means its always 2 power n ( where n is number of call i.e fork().